# xml parsing and latex notation

Tags: python, xml

I am reading some xml and there is information stored as

```
H.P. Dembinski, B. K\'{e}gl, I.C. Mari\c{s}, M. Roth, D. Veberi\v{c}
```

I would like to get this exactly in that format however, instead I get

```
u"H.P. Dembinski, B. K\\'{e}gl, I.C. Mari\\c{s}, M. Roth, D. Veberi\\v{c}"
```

so my question is where in my processing step do I go wrong?
Here is what I do

```
today = some date
base_url = "http://export.arxiv.org/oai2?verb=ListRecords&"
url = (base_url + "from=%s&until=%s&" % (today, today) + "metadataPrefix=arXivRaw")

try:
    response = urllib2.urlopen(url)

except urllib2.HTTPError, e:
    return

rawdata = response.read()
root = ET.fromstring(rawdata)

if root.find(OAI+'ListRecords') is not None:
   for record in root.find(OAI+'ListRecords').findall(OAI+"record"):
     author_string = info.find(ARXIVRAW+"authors").text
```

how can I prevent the introduction of the second \? I know I could do some replace(), but there must be a way just to get the raw text?
thanks
carl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are just seeing the internal representation of the string, it uses double `\\` to show an escaped backslash. If you print the string, you should see only a single `\`. Example -

```
>>> print(u"H.P. Dembinski, B. K\\'{e}gl, I.C. Mari\\c{s}, M. Roth, D. Veberi\\v{c}")
H.P. Dembinski, B. K\'{e}gl, I.C. Mari\c{s}, M. Roth, D. Veberi\v{c}
```

You can also notice the `u` at the starting indicating that its the internal representation of a unicode string.

So it is fine, even when writing to files, etc. It should be working fine and only a single `\` should be coming.